# Bokeh - How to return objects from EventHandler functions

Tags: python, flask, widget, bokeh

I want to return a data.frame object when a upload button(code is from [here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/6096)) is clicked within the bokeh app. Below code,

```
## Load library
import pandas as pd
from xlrd import XLRDError
import io
import base64

from bokeh.layouts import row, column, widgetbox, layout
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CustomJS
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button, Div, TextInput, DataTable, TableColumn, Panel, Tabs
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.plotting import figure

sheet_names_expected = ['Sheet'+str(i) for i in range(1,7)]
## Uploaded Data Handling 
file_source = ColumnDataSource({'file_contents':[], 'file_name':[], 'upload_message':[]})

def file_callback(attr,old,new):
    print('filename:', file_source.data['file_name'])
    #print('filename:', type(file_source.data['file_contents'][0]))
    raw_contents = file_source.data['file_contents'][0]

    prefix, b64_contents = raw_contents.split(",", 1)
    file_contents = base64.b64decode(b64_contents)
    file_io = io.BytesIO(file_contents)

    try:
        df_dict = pd.read_excel(file_io, sheet_name = sheet_names_expected)
        file_source.data['upload_message'] = 'Successfully loaded data'
    except XLRDError:
        file_source.data['upload_message'] = 'One or more of the sheet names are mis-spelled/missing.\n'
    except :
        file_source.data['upload_message'] = 'Error occured while uploading the file. Ensure it\'s a xlsx file'

## How to now have the 6 dataframes within `df_dict` outside the callback function for further analysis and plotting ?



file_source.on_change('data', file_callback)
###########################################################################
## Upload Button Widget
###########################################################################
button = Button(label="Upload Data", button_type="success")
# when butotn is clicked, below code in CustomJS will be called
button.callback = CustomJS(args=dict(file_source=file_source), code = """
function read_file(filename) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = load_handler;
    reader.onerror = error_handler;
    // readAsDataURL represents the file's data as a base64 encoded string
    reader.readAsDataURL(filename);
}

function load_handler(event) {
    var b64string = event.target.result;
    file_source.data = {'file_contents' : [b64string], 'file_name':[input.files[0].name]};
    file_source.trigger("change");
}

function error_handler(evt) {
    if(evt.target.error.name == "NotReadableError") {
        alert("Can't read file!");
    }
}

var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', 'file'); 
input.onchange = function(){
    if (window.FileReader) {
        read_file(input.files[0]);
    } else {
        alert('FileReader is not supported in this browser');
    }
}
input.click();
""")
```

Not sure how to use ColumnDataSource . The excel_file has 6 tabs and thus 6 pandas data.frames will be read into a dictionary by `pd.read_excel()`

Comment: What do you want to do with the data? Are you attempting to update some chart or table or perform a calculation with another python function?

Comment: @Anthonydouc first is to perform a calculation with another python function and then also plot some charts.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, then I think you are somewhat confused as to how bokeh works. I recommend you read through the documentation, and understand how some of the examples in the gallery work.

Never the less, I believe you need to use a ColumnDataSource to achieve what you want. First you can read in your data, then load it into one or more columndatasources. Then when you press the button, it will execute all of the code within the callback function. Read here:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html#columndatasource

The callback function here does the following: 
1: access the existing column source data 
2: run other python functions and then
3: update the existing data, which is stored in the CDS. This will  automatically update the plot.

If you do not use a column data source, there is no way to update the plot without recreating it and updating the html document it is displayed within.

```
from os.path import dirname, abspath
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

button = Button(label='Click')

# replace this with file i/o
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3,4],'y':[10,20,30,40]})

# create a column data source from the read in data
# source.data = dictionary containing the data
# using a CDS will allow any plots or tables
# to automatically update when the source.data
# is modified

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

def mycalc(x):
    """
    Arbitary python function
    """
    x *= 2
    return x


def callback():
    x = source.data['x']
    # compute python based functions here to manipulate data
    x = mycalc(x)
    # update the column data source with the new data
    source.data['x'] = x

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)

p.circle('x','y', source=source)

button.on_click(callback)
curdoc().add_root(row([button, p]))
```

Comment: Hey thanks for sharing. However, I have a upload `button` which will give me the data. Hence, data source is not fixed for me. That is the reason why I need to read within the `callback` function. I shall edit my question with this too, my mistake'

Comment: are the columns fixed that you are plotting? If they are the CDS data fields can be fixed, but the data changes on upload. You can update the data contained within the cds with the uploaded data, which will propagate to the plots.

Comment: No, the data format will be different. For eg I sheet has each machine as a column. So if you machines are installed, then uploaded data will have more columns. Thus I need that to be dynamic. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you better explain what parts of the data are being plotted or tabulated. Are the number of plots or the number of data fields being plotted variable as well? Theres only so much yo can do - update existing plots/tables, add new data series or create new plots with new data.

Comment: No you can add new fields and add new glyphs to the existing figure. For example you could add new circles corresponding to new fields each time you press the button. I just dont know exactly what your question is anymore.

Comment: I only wanted to know if there is a way to create a new `ColumnDataSource`  within the callback function each for the 6 excel tabs that I'm reading from. ? With nothing to assume as the column fields before uploading itself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163178/discussion-between-anthonydouc-and-joel-wilson).